# django object data disappears when I refresh page

Tags: django

When I load the page for the first time, the object data is there (so three links in the example below), after starting runserver on my computer. If I reload the object data is not longer there (so zero links in the example below).

## template

```
{% for url in urls %}
   <a href="{{ url }}">
      link
   </a>
{% endfor %}
```

## view

```
class IntroView(View):

    template_name = '[app_name]/template.html'
    model_names = ['shoe', 'hat', 'bag']
    urls = [reverse_lazy('%s:%s' % ('[app_name]', name)) for name in model_names]
    dict_to_template = {'urls': urls}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=self.dict_to_template)
```

It's probably something really simple, but it's got me.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your example explains the behaviour you are seeing.

If you use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, then you will get that error, because the generator will be consumed the first time the view runs.

```
class IntroView(View):
    template_name = '[app_name]/template.html'
    model_names = ['shoe', 'hat', 'bag']

    urls = (reverse_lazy('%s:%s' % ('[app_name]', name)) for name in model_names)
    dict_to_template = {'urls': urls}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=self.dict_to_template)
```

You could avoid the problem by moving the code into the `get()` method so that it runs every time the view runs.

```
class IntroView(View):
    template_name = '[app_name]/template.html'
    model_names = ['shoe', 'hat', 'bag']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        urls = (reverse_lazy('%s:%s' % ('[app_name]', name)) for name in model_names)
        dict_to_template = {'urls': urls}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=dict_to_template)
```